# WCF - Setting Policy for UsernameToken

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soapui

I received an updated WSDL for a service I'm consuming which has below Policy added

```
    <wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="UsernameToken">
<ns0:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512">
 <wsp:Policy>
 <ns0:UsernameToken ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
 <wsp:Policy>
  <ns0:WssUsernameToken10 /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns0:UsernameToken>
  </wsp:Policy>
  </ns0:SupportingTokens>
  </wsp:Policy>
```

I have updated my reference by right clicking the Service Reference --> Configure Service option inside Visual Studio.  This generated a customBinding replacing my previous basicHttpBinding

```
<customBinding>
            <binding name="myBindingName">
                <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/cm/CM-CustConnAcctDetailExtract':    -->
                <!--    <wsdl:binding name='CM-CustConnAcctDetailExtractSoapBinding'>    -->
                <!--        <ns0:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512">..</ns0:SupportingTokens>    -->
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
```

Do I need to use this customBinding only? Or is there any option in basicBinding that makes it work?

If I use my basicBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential, I get below error:

> The provided URI is Invalid; HTTPS is expected

I ran this using SoapUI.  In addition to UserName and Passwrod, I had to supply `WSS-PasswordType` as `PasswordText`.  Without supplying this parameter, I get an error in SoapUI

> Error on verifying message against security policy Error code:1000

I'm not sure how to supply WSS-PasswordType in my basicHttpBinding.

My basicHttpBinding is as below

```
protected BasicHttpBinding GetBinding()
    {
        return new BasicHttpBinding()
                   {
                       Name = "BasicHttpBinding",
                       ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2, 0),
                       SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2, 0),
                       Security =
                           {
                               Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
                               Transport =
                                   {
                                       ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic,
                                       ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None,
                                       Realm = ""
                                   },
                               Message =
                                   {
                                       ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
                                       AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default
                                   }
                           },
                       MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                       MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
                       ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
                       {
                           MaxBytesPerRead = 8192
                       }
                   };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to work this through by changing my binding to Custom Binding

```
protected CustomBinding GetCustomBinding()
    {
        var customBinding = new CustomBinding() { Name = "CustomBinding" };

        customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11 });
        var securityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        securityBindingElement.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
        securityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        customBinding.Elements.Add(securityBindingElement);
        customBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement());

        return customBinding;
    }
```